# Cannot access other pages in paginated JSON array

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I am trying to put together a paginated view of data returned from a remote API, however I can only see the first page of data. When I mouse over the pagination buttons the links to other pages of data are being built correctly, yet when clicked, they take the user back to the root of the search page and the recently obtained data is lost.

I am using a `POST` request on my form to request the data, because when I try and use a `GET` request my EJS template complains about the `forEach` loop that displays the data. When I change the loop to a `for` loop data is not displayed.

Would anybody be able to help resolve this pagination issue please?  My code is below.

```
// app.js
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
var nav = [{ Link: '/Map', Text: 'Map' }, { Link: '/Street', Text: 'Street' }];
var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.set('views', './src/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use('/Street', streetRouter);

app.listen(port, function (err) {
if (err) {
    throw err;
}
console.log('Running server on port ' + port);
});

// streetRoutes.js
var express = require('express');
var streetRouter = express.Router();

var router = function (nav) {
var historyCardService = require('../services/historyCardService')();
var streetController = require('../controllers/streetController')(historyCardService, nav);

streetRouter.use(streetController.middleware);

streetRouter.route('/')
    .get(streetController.getStreet);

streetRouter.route('/')
    .post(streetController.getStreetByName);

return streetRouter;
};
module.exports = router;

// streetController.js
var streetController = function (historyCardService, nav) {

var getStreet = function (req, res) {
    console.log('>>> getStreet');
    res.render('streetView', {
        title: 'Street',
        nav: nav,
        streetname: { streetname: 'waiting for input...' }
    });
};

var getStreetByName = function (req, res) {
    console.log('>>> getStreetByName');
    var streetName = req.body.street;
    var streets = [{ streetname: streetName }];


    // Service.
    historyCardService.getHistRecordCard(encodeURI(streetName), function (err, results) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }

        var parsedJSON = JSON.parse(results);

        var pageSize = 5;
        var totalRecords = parsedJSON.length;
        var pageCount = Math.round(totalRecords / pageSize);
        var currentPage = 1;
        var paginatedStreet = [];
        var JSONList = [];

        // Split parsedJSON into groups for pagination.
        while (parsedJSON.length > 0) {
            paginatedStreet.push(parsedJSON.splice(0, pageSize));
        }

        // Set current page if specified as get variables e.g. /?page=2
        if (typeof req.query.page !== 'undefined') {
            currentPage = +req.query.page;
            console.log('>>> Ying ying ying' + currentPage);
        }

        JSONList = paginatedStreet[+currentPage - 1];

        JSONList.forEach(function (item) {
           console.log('>>> ' + item.address + ' ' + item.preview_url + ' ' + item.pageCount);
        });

        console.log('>>> Request for History Record Cards at: ' + streetName);
        console.log('>>> Total # of records: ' + totalRecords);
        console.log('>>> # of items on page: ' + JSONList.length);
        console.log('>>> # of pages: ' + pageCount);

        res.render('streetResultsView', {
            title: 'Street',
            nav: nav,
            streetname: JSONList,
            pageSize: pageSize,
            totalRecords: totalRecords,
            pageCount: pageCount,
            currentPage: currentPage
        });
    });
};
return {
    getStreet: getStreet,
    getStreetByName: getStreetByName,
    middleware: middleware
    }; 
};
module.exports = streetController;

<!-- streetView.ejs -->
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<!--bower:css-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<!--endbower-->
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<!-- endbower -->
<!--inject:css-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/site.css">
<!--endinject-->
<!--inject:js-->
<script src="/js/site.js"></script>
<!--endinject-->

<title>SHBC - Leagcy Planning Search</title>

<!-- Nav view -->
<% include ./partials/navView %>

<div id="wrapper" class="container-fluid">
    <div id="main" class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Start Main -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <h4>Planning History Search</h4>
            <div>
                <a href="/" class="btn btn-sm btn-default"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i> Back</a>
                <!-- Street Entry Field view -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <form name="streetSearchForm" action="/Street" method="post">
                        <label for="street">Please enter a street name within Surrey Heath</label>
                        <input type="text" id="street" name="street" class="form-control" />
                        <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <!-- Results List -->
                <div class="row">
                    <!-- History Record Card Results view -->
                    <!-- -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End Main -->
</div>
<!-- Footer view -->
<% include ./partials/footerView %>
</div>

<!-- streetResultsView.ejs -->
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<!--bower:css-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<!--endbower-->
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<!-- endbower -->
<!--inject:css-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/site.css">
<!--endinject-->
<!--inject:js-->
<script src="/js/site.js"></script>
<!--endinject-->
<title>SHBC - Leagcy Planning Search</title>

<!-- Nav view -->
<% include ./partials/navView %>

<div id="wrapper" class="container-fluid">
    <div id="main" class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Start Main -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <h4>Planning History Search</h4>
                <div>
                    <a href="/" class="btn btn-sm btn-default"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i> Back</a>
                    <!-- Street Entry Field view -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <form name="streetSearchForm" action="/Street" method="post">
                            <label for="street">Please enter a street name within Surrey Heath</label>
                            <input type="text" id="street" name="street" class="form-control" />
                            <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Results List -->
                    <div class="row">
                        <!-- History Record Card Results view -->

                        <ul class="list-group">
                            <% streetname.forEach(function (item) { %>
                                <li class="list-group-item"><a href="<%= item.preview_url %>" target="_blank"><%= item.address %></a></li>
                             <% }) %>
                        </ul>

                        <% if (pageCount > 1) { %>
                            <ul class="pagination">
                                <% if (currentPage > 1) { %>
                                    <li><a href="/Street?page=1">&laquo;</a></li>
                                <% } %>
                                <% var i = 1;
                                if (currentPage > 5) {
                                    i = +currentPage - 4;
                                } %>
                                <% if (i !== 1) { %>
                                    <li class="disabled"><a href="#">...</a></li>
                                <% } %>
                                <% for (i; i<=pageCount; i++) { %>
                                    <% if (currentPage == i) { %>
                                    <li class="active"><span><%= i %> <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></span></li>
                                <% } else { %>
                                    <li><a href="/Street?page=<%= i %>"><%= i %></a></li>
                                <% } %>
                                <% if (i == (+currentPage + 4)) { %>
                                    <li class="disabled"><a href="#">...</a></li>
                                    <% break; } %>
                                <% } %>
                                <% if (currentPage != pageCount) { %>
                                    <li><a href="/Street?page=<%= pageCount %>">&raquo;</a></li>
                                <% } %>
                            </ul>
                        <% } %>

                        <!-- -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End Main -->
    </div>
    <!-- Footer view -->
    <% include ./partials/footerView %>
</div>

// sample JSON data.
[
    {
        "address":"WINDRUSH - 44 DELTA ROAD - CHOBHAM",
        "preview_url":"https://surreyheath.box.com/s/ilomxp3luk9xp1q4grdrc4cxjem4hxvj",
        "rank":0.1},
    {
        "address":"38 DELTA ROAD",
        "preview_url":"https://surreyheath.box.com/s/5bbjk5y6ptusd7s4p400qfmaylntx85g",
        "rank":0.1},
    {
        "address":"18 DELTA CLOSE",
        "preview_url":"https://surreyheath.box.com/s/14tiicq1su747irh7mukhoyg97u8t8f1",
        "rank":0.1},
    {
        "address":"35 DELTA ROAD",
        "preview_url":"https://surreyheath.box.com/s/jmjtou0jv3o55wt5hpg8zlbwvt568p87",
        "rank":0.1},
    {
        "address":"35A DELTA ROAD - CHOBHAM",
        "preview_url":"https://surreyheath.box.com/s/uj3v2n5q2dzjkkopi5vqvj539crvwl62",
        "rank":0.1},
    {
        "address":"37 DELTA ROAD",
        "preview_url":"https://surreyheath.box.com/s/0havuuz7ylrvq1m5l9nor1pde28mr9ap",
        "rank":0.1},
    {
        "address":"39 DELTA ROAD - CHOBHAM",
        "preview_url":"https://surreyheath.box.com/s/s07cl401bjl7aixl0d2yxgawo0o0l07d",
        "rank":0.1},
    {
        "address":"ROSLEN - 56 DELTA ROAD - CHOBHAM",
        "preview_url":"https://surreyheath.box.com/s/9u4uqckp3p2y3djifho2y5dnzrnwsnj4",
        "rank":0.1},
    {
        "address":"RHO - 54 DELTA ROAD - CHOBHAM",
        "preview_url":"https://surreyheath.box.com/s/vcrutb20f0pkv6ykbvk7qxy6rbknn91y",
        "rank":0.1},
    {
        "address":"42A DELTA ROAD - CHOBHAM",
        "preview_url":"https://surreyheath.box.com/s/rxb1r11vlxv37mzejycp5lex02ftdmqi",
        "rank":0.1
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change these lines: `streetRouter.route('/street/:name')` and `var streetName = req.params.street` (and also whatever generates the links, so it matches that).  If it doesn't work right, I would go back to GET for that route.. if you have some issue with the for/forEach you can post here or maybe just add a try/catch around it.

Comment: Thanks for your time Jason my pagination is now fixed. For clarity, I used `req.query.street`.